# Summation of $e^{-n^p}$ for p>0

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove that $ \forall p>0$ $$ \sum _{n \geq 1} e^{-n^p}<\infty  $$ I have tried many theorems that I know from analysis but I failed with all when $0<p\leq1$. I have prooved though that for $p>1$, $  e^{-n^p}\leq \frac{1}{n^p}$ and so it converges. Any ideas for the other case?

Comment: could express it as a double summation and try to manipulate then change the order?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying.. Which is going to be the second' s summation bound?

Comment: $$
e^{n^p }  = 1 + n^p  + \frac{(n^p)^2}{2!} +\cdots  + \frac{{(n^p )^{\left\lceil {2/p} \right\rceil } }}{{\left\lceil {2/p} \right\rceil !}} +  \cdots  \ge \frac{{(n^p )^{\left\lceil {2/p} \right\rceil } }}{{\left\lceil {2/p} \right\rceil !}} \ge \frac{{n^2 }}{{\left\lceil {2/p} \right\rceil !}}
$$

Comment: Prove is the verb and proof is the noun.

Comment: I would say, for any $p>0$, prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{-n^p}}{1/n^2} = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p>1/m$.

We know that $e^{u}>u^{m}$ for large $u>0$. Plugging in $u=n^{p}$ we get $1/e^{u}<1/n^{pm}$. Now note that $pm>1$ and so $\sum_{n}1/n^{pm}<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks I wouldn't have thought it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see
, $e^x>x^k/k!\,,\, \forall k\in \mathbb{N},x\in\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true for $x=-100$ and $k=2$. (But yes, the $x>0$ case is enough to get us through here).

Comment: Yes, we need $x$ to non negative

Comment: I'll change it to line up with the comments